# Getting Effort or Hours to Roll up a item-type hierarchy

Tags: azure-devops

I have the following hierarchy setup:

```
Epic
Feature
Backlog Item
Task
```

The problem that I have is that the hours I put in at the task levels, do not roll up to the Backlog Item, Feature, and Epic levels. I need a way for capturing estimated and actual hours or efforts (whatever is available), and have them automatically roll up to the highest level (Epic in this case).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Rollback is limited out of the box, as you can see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/xml/support-rollup-of-work-and-other-fields).

If you need something more complex, you can look at the (TFS) Aggregator project on GitHub https://github.com/tfsaggregator/ (disclosure: I am the main contributor).

Comment: Interesting. Thank you. I will check it out.